# Project JAVA (library TimerTask)

Tags: java, time, timer, timertask

I have to do a project for my school and I have a problem that I could not solve with the library TimeTask in JAVA.
In the run function of TimerTAsk I can't call a function with the object as a parameter that called the function running at the beginning .
Here is my code
thank you for your help

public void running() {

```
        Clock clock = Clock.systemDefaultZone() ;
        Instant instant = clock.instant() ;         //< allows to see the time
        System.out.println(instant);
        
        Model game = new Model() ;
        this.listCentrale = new ArrayList<>();
        this.listHabitant = new ArrayList<>();
        this.listHabitation = new ArrayList<>();
        this.listCentralName = new ArrayList<>() ;
        
        //updateGeneral(new Meteo(),this) ; // here for example it works
        Timer chrono = new Timer() ; //< chrono permettant d'actualiser le jeux
        
        chrono.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                
                public void run() {
                
            System.out.println("Attention !");
           updateGeneral(new Meteo(),this) ;
```

here I have an eroor I just want to call my  first object which has called the function running

```
            if( pollution == 0) //< If the user want to quite the game with the listner when he push the good the button
            {
                cancel() ;
            }
                
            }
                
                
                
        }, 5000,1000);//< here we wait first 5sec and we do our update general every 10 sec
    }
```

Comment: Do not include extraneous code when posting here. Do not make the readers here work so hard as to discern the relevant code from the irrelevant. Put in the effort to create clear concise example code, as brief as possible.

Comment: I started to write an Answer, but cannot. You have included irrelevant code while omitting necessary code. Tip: Learn about the Executors framework rather than use Timer & TimerTask. Search Stack Overflow to learn more as this has been covered many many times already.

Comment: Your title is vague. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.